# Nodejs EPERM: operation not permitted on file downloaded with getBlobToLocalFile

Tags: node.js, azure-storage

I'm using on nodejs the getBlobToLocalFile method from azure-storage to download a file.

```
import {BlobService, common, ErrorOrResult} from "azure-storage";    

getBlobToLocalFile(container: string, blob: string, localFileName: string,
                           callbackOrOptions:  ErrorOrResult<BlobService.BlobResult> | BlobService.GetBlobRequestOptions,
                           callback?: ErrorOrResult<BlobService.BlobResult>): any;
```

When trying to use the file, the error below is thrown:

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Work...\downloads\testImage.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site and it works well with following code:

```
var storage = require('azure-storage');
const containerName="container";
const blobName="me.jpg";
const localFileName="aaa.jpg"
var blobService = storage.createBlobService(connectionString);
blobService.getBlobToLocalFile(containerName,blobName,localFileName, function (error) 
{
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
      } 
    else{
    }
})
```

[image]

You can refer to the following ways to troubleshooting:

1.Run the node command prompt as administrator.

2.Go to `c:/users/{pc name}/`, right click `.yarnrc` file properties and unhidden it.

[image]

3. Clean cache with `npm cache clean` and then retry it.